How to make an executable Java application (app) for ARM64 architecture on MacOSX
I am trying to make my Java+JavaFX application work on MacOSX on ARM64 architecture. I cannot use Rosetta, since my client does not want to install and use Rosetta, and I need to use Java8 since JavaFX used in the application is from Java version 8. I can already build an Intel architecture (x86_64) application by using the sh.tak.appbundler, but I am failing to make it work on ARM64 architecture.
I suspect the problem is in Mac not being able to understand that it needs to use the packaged version of Java, but have no idea how to solve it.
Does anyone has any ideas how to solve this ?
In order to solve this problem i have tried the following:

Downloaded Java 8 ARM64 from OpenJDK (jdk-8u411-macosx-aarch64), and install it.
Changed my maven entry for appbundler to include this new Java in the application package I generate:
Compiled appbundler (from https://github.com/federkasten/appbundle-maven-plugin/blob/master/build.sh) to receive the ARM64 JavaAppLauncher:
Built the application and included the JavaAppLauncher built in the previous step (I did not change my info.plist which I can supply if necessary)

I can see that my application is seen as Kind: Application (Apple silicon), which is correct, however, when I try to run it, it crashes.
If I double click it I get generic crash report from my MAC, and if I run JavaAppLanucher inside the package by using the command line I also get the error, but it seems that Java at least gets invoked.
I can run only the jar file with all the dependencies normally.
Does anyone has experience in packaging the Java applications this way ?

“I need to use Java8 since JavaFX used in the application is from Java version 8.”  I’m pretty sure that is not true.  You would have to download the JavaFX SDK separately when building the application, but all code written for JavaFX 8 will work with later versions of JavaFX.

why do you need to use an appBuilder? just execute the jar

You should be able to compile on a modern JDK and equivalent modern JavaFX version, then build a native bundle with jpackage. Unless you are using classes that are not part of the public API, everything is back-compatible.

I am using JavaFX classes that are not back-compatible, and my team is gone so I cannot port this application to newer Java.

"I am using JavaFX classes that are not back-compatible" That's an unfortunate decision for which you are now paying the price. Probably your best option (and the only supported option) is to reimplement the parts of the app that use non-public API classes. I understand that's almost certainly not the answer you want.

”Downloaded Java 8 ARM64 from OpenJDK (jdk-8u411-macosx-aarch64)” -> Most OpenJDK versions, even in the Java 8 timeframe, don’t include JavaFX. Only Oracle Java 8 versions used to include JavaFX (though I don’t think they do anymore).  And even if later Oracle Java 8 versions included JavaFX I doubt they would include a back port of aarch64 support for modern macs that didn’t even exist at the time JavaFX for Java 8 had its last feature release.

Simply show this to your client: https://endoflife.date/oracle-jdk... Just saying...
